# Python 2.7.9 change to 3.4.2 when django project is activated

Tags: python, django, cmd

I have a problem with python installation.

I was in python 3.4.2 and I want to migrate to python 2.7.9

I already intalled python 2.7.9, change the path in the Environment Variable.

So here is the probleme : When I lauch python shell in my Desktop or in another folder the version of the shell is 2.7.9 and when I launch it in my project file after I activate django (*.\Scripts\activate*), the shell change to 3.4.2. How Can I resolve this ?

**Screenshot:** (You can see the whole operation in de cmd)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Django that you are activating, but a virtualenv. That virtualenv has Python 3.4 installed inside it. You will need to recreate it using Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for your message, how should I do it ? uninstall virtualenv and reinstall it ?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall virtualenv itself, you need to delete that particular virtualenv and recreate it with the `-p` flag to specify the path to your Python 2.7 installation.